# Change in database structure

Tags: database, data-structures

We already have a database structure, but it is the structure without normalization and very confused and in need of change, but already has a large volume of stored data, for example, all financial data company, which finance department officials are afraid of losing.
We are undecided about remodeling the entire structure of the database and retrieve the most basic and all that is possible, or continue with the same model along with their problems.

I wonder if someone has made a change like this, if you can actually transfer the data to a new structure.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called "database conversion".    It is a very common practice, but it must be done carefully and methodically, ideally by someone who has done many of them and knows the pitfalls. It is not to be done casually by any means. Moreover, it is not unusual in the financial sector to run the "old system" in parallel with the new system for a couple of months, to reconcile month-end reports, before saying goodbye to the old system. Running parallel is a PITA, and can only be done if all of the conversion programs are in place, but it's better to be safe than sorry when the numbers must be correct to the penny.

Answer (score 2):

Before you do any thing I would BACKUP!!! Next I would create a new database with the ideas that you had in mind. Remember this is were all the real work should be once this is created it is hard to go back. Put a lot of thought in and make the design a bullet proof tiger to the design of your company. Next create some procedures to transform the data you have in the new database as you see fit. It would help if you mentioned the platform(s) you are using and mabey provide some generic examples

I have found SSIS packages work well for projects like this if you are using SQLSERVER. While you will need to still write your transforms out the packages make the work easier for others to see what is happening

Anything can be done by you the developer. However it might make business sense to check out various 3rd party tools. There are many out there and depending on exactly what you are doing you may benefit from doing some research

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the way I solved this is by re-design a new database, then I made a script that copies the data from the old schema to the new one. It's not an easy task because you need  to take care of what you are copying from the old model to the new one but it's doable!

Answer (score 0):

absolutely you can migrate the data to an new structure.  The real question is 'how difficult (expensive/time consuming/reliable) will the migration be?'  To answer that question one would have to know

1. The accuracy of the existing data - does it have gaps, duplication that disagrees with each other and no way to resolve, errors, etc.
2. What structure do you imagine going to and is this going to introduce complexity to the migration
3. the skill level of the person/team doing the migration
4. How long the migration will take and will the platforms be changing (either the live system being modified or the new system design changing)